# Parse and read response from Bing Maps REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

Using Bing Maps Rest Service to find the longitude/latitude for an address. I'm getting the response back fine, but I'm having trouble with the correct syntax to reference the long/lat fields (see screen shot from debugger). I've tried

```
latitude = x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0].GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[0];

longitude = x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0].GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[1];
```

but they don't compile.

Here is the rest service call ... (not in screen shot).

```
      private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback)
  {
     System.Net.WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
     {
        if (callback != null)
        {
           DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
           callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) as Response);
        }
     };
     wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
  }
```

[Studio Debugging Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd6HA.png)

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to compile it?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'GeocodePoints' and no accessible extension method 'GeocodePoints' accepting a first argument of type 'Resource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Northwind C:\Users\Hugh\source\repos\Northwind\Northwind\Pages\CustomerPages\Details.cshtml.cs 54 Active

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screen shot, it seems as `x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0]` is of type `Location`, whereas the base class for that array is `Resource`. Try casting it before accessing the values:

```
var location = (Location)x.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0];
latitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[0];
longitude = location.GeocodePoints[0].Coordinates[1];
```